# i write a code to implement queue using arays in java. But it shows me wrong output

Tags: java, queue

i write a code to implement queue using arays in java. But it shows me wrong output.
The output should be 2 , 3 , 4  But output showed is 0 , 2 , 3 , 4.

my question was over here.
But this stupid site algorithm says that your question contain mostly code. But if i finished writing my problem then how can i write more words to it. Therefore i am writing these sentences.

```
import java.util.*;
public class first {
  public static class queque{
    static int arr[];
    static int size;
    static int rear;
    queque(int n){
       arr = new int[n];
        size=n;
       int rear = -1;
    }
    public static boolean isEmpty(){
        return rear==-1;
    }`your text`
    public static void add(int data){
     if(rear == size-1){
        System.out.println("queue is full")`your text`;
     } 
     rear++;
     arr[rear]=data;
    }
    public static int remove(){
        if(isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("empty queue");
            return -1;
        }
        int front = arr[0];
        for(int i=0;i<rear;i++){
            arr[i]=arr[i+1];
        }
        rear--;
        
        return front;
    }
    public static int peek(){
        if(isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("empty queue");
            return -1;
        }
        return arr[0];
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    queque q = new queque(5);
    q.add(2);
    q.add(3);
    q.add(4);
    while(!q.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println(q.peek());
        q.remove();
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: First, you could actually try to highlight where in your implementation you're facing an issue rather than just dumping everything and telling us the output is wrong expecting us to debug your entire implementation for you. Second, you'd know how to improve your question if you read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Third, if you have a problem with the way something in the site works, you can check [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) for discussions regarding this topic or post your own discussion rather than just calling it "stupid" and still asking for help :)

Comment: Surely you tried to debug your code with a debugger before posting a rant on this "stupid" website ?

Comment: You need to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have issue on this line

```
int rear = -1;
```

change it to

```
rear = -1;
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if it explained why this works.

Comment: because the code ```int rear = -1;``` is local to that method only, it doesn't affect the global ```rear``` variable